# Is that correct work of recycleView android 7.0+?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have list of data, and size of data = 7, but when I try to display all the elements, it displays only 6 and in the debug mode in the method onBindViewHolder the last binds position is 5. I thought that was some bugs with my list, so i added 8th element, but it all the same displays only 6 elements.

On android lower than 7.0 everything works properly

**Adapter**

```
 public class BottomNavigationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BottomNavigationAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


private ArrayList<BottomNavigationData> bottomNavigationDatas = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;


public BottomNavigationAdapter(ArrayList<BottomNavigationData> bnl, Context context) {
    bottomNavigationDatas = bnl;
    mContext = context;
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtview;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBottomItemIcon);
        txtview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBottomTitle);
    }
}


@Override
public BottomNavigationAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bottom_navigation_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BottomNavigationAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    BottomNavigationData currentNavigationData = bottomNavigationDatas.get(position);
    String image_url = Constants.SERVER_HOST + "/" + currentNavigationData.image;
    Glide.with(mContext).load(image_url).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.txtview.setText(currentNavigationData.name);
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }

    });

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (bottomNavigationDatas != null) ? bottomNavigationDatas.size() : 0;
}
```

**recycle view initialisation**

```
rvBottomNavigation = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvBottomNavigation);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        rvBottomNavigation.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);

   bottomNavigationAdapter = new BottomNavigationAdapter(bottomNavigationDatas, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        rvBottomNavigation.setAdapter(bottomNavigationAdapter);
        bottomNavigationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

my output on android 7.0+:

[image: android 7.0]

output on lower than 7.0:

[image]

So as you can see, i have one more item at the end.
Code is exactly the same. How can i fix it?

**EDIT**
added full code of adapter

**item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_margin"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBottomItemIcon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBottomTitle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**my_fragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.GiftsActivity">
    <mfp.avdm.chudobox.custom.HeaderGridView
        android:id="@+id/gvGoods"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbare">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvBottomNavigation"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bottomNavigationDatas.size();
}

Comment: @VishvaDave it's the same with my code, i just  added cheching if list is null

Comment: Actually your code seems perfect. that's why i suggested this. even you can also try with instead of getActivity write class.this or context

Comment: @VishvaDave i thought that problem is with my device, but then i run my app on emulator, and the issue repeats on 7.0 and 8.0 too

Comment: @Toper can you add a full code of your adapter

Comment: @tamtom yes, added

Comment: code seems fine ,check list size and  organize your recycle view initialisation in this way, first instantiate adapter, then set layout mgr, then set adapter and in your adapter, use onclick listeners inside onCreateViewHolder

Comment: @Cyborg91 list size is fine, i don't understand all of the rest your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems fine but I am sure this is not the way to do it,

1. You should null check your arrayList in your activity itself, then proceed to set adapter.
2. For adapter,you should provide activityContext rather than applicationContext, adapters often hold listeners to open activities or to show toasts, it that case it should be activityContext not applicationContext
3. For your problem, I will suggest setting layout manager after setting adapter. In this way, you won't need to call notifyDatasetChang.

**Updated part**

In your xml, you are adding RecyclerView inside horizontal scrollview which is the reason its giving trouble. Take your recyclerview outside the horizontal scrollview because you are setting the LinearLayoutManager with horizontal orientation in your code anyways. Then set both height and width of the recyclerview to match_parent. Also, if you don't want to add anything else in the footer view, you can remove the linearLayout and set your recyclerview as footer with width=match_parent and height=60dp.

Don't forget to delete horizontalscrollview code.

Comment: It's a good advice. I changed my code as you adviced, but i still have the same problem

Comment: In your code, you are not supposed to initialise any object which you gonna evaluate from constructor. Don't initialise your arrayList, that is don't call ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>. Just declare it globally with ArrayList<Object> arrayList and let your constructor initialise the arrayList.

Comment: Oh, i missed this mistake, thank you, but it wont help too

Comment: Shared xmls as you asked